# How to check if a line from a file is empty with bash

Tags: bash

I have a while loop which reads lines from a file using read line.
Then I want to check if the line is empty or not, how can I do it?
I already found questions about lines with space or about a variable in this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the test:

```
[ -z "$line" ]
```

From the bash man page:

> -z string
>             True if the length of string is zero.

Comment: oh, shucks! beat me to it! nice job

Answer (score 1):

The `-n` operator checks if a string is not empty:

```
while read line    
do
    if [ -n "$line" ]
        echo $line
    fi
done < file.txt
```

If you'd want to exclude strings containing only whitespace, you could use bash's pattern replacement `${var//find/replacement}`. For example:

```
if -n [ "${line//[[:space:]]/}" ]
```

Comment: If you wrote `[ -n "$line" ]`, I'd be happy.  I suspect that `bash` does allow what you wrote to work (though I'm not sure I understand the logic by which it does it there and not elsewhere), but I'm old school enough to be uncomfortable without the double quotes.  Were you to use other related shells (such as Bourne and - I believe - Korn), then the notation without quotes would not work.

Comment: Thanks, interesting, found a full explanation [here at point #4](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)